# I want to overlay a separate lineplot on a boxplot. I am using BOXPLOT function but think I may need to use GGPLOT

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my first attempt at BOXPLOT. It is clearly suboptimal in how I have set up the values and names but it works. Now I want to overlay a different line on top of the boxplot which I think means I need to use a different package like GGPLOT.
The line I overlay will have contain one value per year 1990 to 2030.
Advice on how to do this would be much appreciated.

```
UNCERT <-read.csv(file = 'CEHV16U5MorUncertstats.csv')

str(UNCERT)
Y1990 <- UNCERT[,2]
Y1991 <- UNCERT[,3]
Y1992 <- UNCERT[,4]
Y1993 <- UNCERT[,5]
Y1994 <- UNCERT[,6]
Y1995 <- UNCERT[,7]
Y1996 <- UNCERT[,8]
Y1997 <- UNCERT[,9]
Y1998 <- UNCERT[,10]
Y1999 <- UNCERT[,11]
Y2000 <- UNCERT[,12]
Y2001 <- UNCERT[,13]
Y2002 <- UNCERT[,14]
Y2003 <- UNCERT[,15]
Y2004 <- UNCERT[,16]
Y2005 <- UNCERT[,17]
Y2006 <- UNCERT[,18]
Y2007 <- UNCERT[,19]
Y2008 <- UNCERT[,20]
Y2009 <- UNCERT[,21]
Y2010 <- UNCERT[,22]
Y2011 <- UNCERT[,23]
Y2012 <- UNCERT[,24]
Y2013 <- UNCERT[,25]
Y2014 <- UNCERT[,26]
Y2015 <- UNCERT[,27]
Y2016 <- UNCERT[,28]
Y2017 <- UNCERT[,29]
Y2018 <- UNCERT[,30]
Y2019 <- UNCERT[,31]
Y2020 <- UNCERT[,32]
Y2021 <- UNCERT[,33]
Y2022 <- UNCERT[,34]
Y2023 <- UNCERT[,35]
Y2024 <- UNCERT[,36]
Y2025 <- UNCERT[,37]
Y2026 <- UNCERT[,38]
Y2027 <- UNCERT[,39]
Y2028 <- UNCERT[,40]
Y2029 <- UNCERT[,41]
Y2030 <- UNCERT[,42]

boxplot(Y1990,Y1991,Y1992,Y1993,Y1994,Y1995,Y1996,Y1997,Y1998,Y1999,Y2000,
        Y2001,Y2002,Y2003,Y2004,Y2005,Y2006,Y2007,Y2008,Y2009,Y2010,
        Y2011,Y2012,Y2013,Y2014,Y2015,Y2016,Y2017,Y2018,Y2019,Y2020,
        Y2021,Y2022,Y2023,Y2024,Y2025,Y2026,Y2027,Y2028,Y2029,Y2030,
        names = c("1990","","","","","1995","","","","","2000",
               "","","","","2005","","","","","2010",
                "","","","","2015","","","","","2020",
                "","","","","2025","","","","","2030"),
        las = 2, cex.axis = 1,
        main = "Under Five Mortality",
        xlab = "Year",
        ylab = "Under Five deaths per 1000 live births",
        border = "black", 
        whisklty = 1)
```

[image: Boxplot of Under 5 mortality over 40 years]

Comment: How are you summarising the values for each year into one value? The mean?

Comment: Hi Claire, are you able to share the file "CEHV16U5MorUncertstats.csv"? It makes it a lot easier to troubleshoot when we have a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi I have added a Dropbox link which I hope will work. The line I want to overlay will be a separate one i.e. not the mean of this data or similar but data from a different source.

Comment: Hi Neil the line I want to overlay will be from a different source, one value for each year from 1990 to 2030.